# Forms are Read-Only in Open Office Base

Tags: openoffice, database, read-only, openoffice-base

I'm in Open Office Base and I want to add records to an existing table/form, but it says read-only. I've already checked the Properties

How can I add new records?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible answers to this query:

1. To be editable in OO Base, every table must have a primary key defined.  Microsoft Access does not insist on this.
2. OO Base Forms (used to) have "Read-Only" in the title bar - this only referred to the Form definition, not the accessed data.